# Unable to restore Test project Nuget packages Spring.NET 3.0 GA

Tags: .net, spring, testing, nuget

I have just pulled the latest from Spring.NET 3.0. I successfully restored the package for CORE spring projects but I was unable to restore the package of all Tests projects. I am using VS 2019.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

build.cmd runs fine and weird error is gone after restart visual studio.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.